# Change error log location at runtime

Tags: php, .htaccess, logging

I'm running a PHP script on a server where I can't access the error log. Can I change the log location at the runtime (or with .htaccess), so it's stored in a different directory which I can access?

If this is not possible, would you recommend another solution? (I can't see the errors in the browser window as the script is called from a remote web service.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have permissions from `php.ini` you can use this code in your root .htaccess:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag log_errors on
php_value error_log /path/to/PHP_errors.log
```